# How to change two background images in the same page at the same time using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am redesigning a website where a problem occurs.
I want to change background image of the `<body>` and is able to change it successfully but when I place another background image in the `<div>` tag and want to change it at the same time then `<body>` background image changes successfully but the background image of the `<div>` is not changing with it.

here below is the code.

HTML:

```
<div id="firstimage">
</div>
<div class="bullets">
    <ul>
         <a href="#"><li onclick="backgroundImage1()">&#9898;</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li onclick="backgroundImage2()">&#9898;</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li onclick="backgroundImage3()">&#9898;</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(homepage-BG-handmade.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#firstimage {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(handcrafted-menswear1.png);
    background-position: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function backgroundImage1() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('homepage-BG-handmade.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("firstimage").style.backgroundImage =
        "url('handcrafted-menswear1.png')";
}

function backgroundImage2() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('New-Shirts-BG1.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("firstimage").style.backgroundImage =
        "url('home-overlay-definition.png')";
}

function backgroundImage3() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('bg-image-shipping21.jpg')";
    document.getElementById("firstimage").style.backgroundImage =
        "url('free-shipping2.png')";
}
```

Comment: You had a typo in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<a href="#"><li onclick="backgroundImage1()"<>&#9898;</li></a>`

Into:

`<a href="#"><li onclick="backgroundImage1()">&#9898;</li></a>`

A simple typo breaks your site, this should work.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRoJyy?editors=1011)